# Styling ASP.NET MVC validation errors does not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have styled up .field-validation-error as shown

```
.field-validation-error{ color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

and also .input-validation-error

```
.input-validation-error{ border: 2px solid red; }
```

but unfortunately, my validation error and input field are same color as before.

Here is html code

```
@model MovieApp.ViewModel.CustomerFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<h1>New customer</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.BirthDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipTypeId
        ,new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes,"Id","Name")
        ,"Select Membership Type"
        ,new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter) Subscribed to newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Customer.Id)

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
}
```

Comment: Can you add your view HTML of your form?

Comment: @zgood Hope you find out where the problem is ...

Comment: Are you using the script `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`?

Comment: it may put the class `.has-error` on the `.form-group`. Can you see if this style works for you: `.has-error .form-control { border: 2px solid red; }`? I believe the `.field-validation-error` goes on the span that is created with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` fyi

Comment: @zgood still doesn't work ....